# Designate files/folders as read-only in iCloud Drive

Tags: macos, icloud

I just recently started using iCloud Drive.
I would like to designate one folder, called `archive`, as read-only.
Its files must be protected from change, and I want to make sure I don't accidentally alter or delete them.
Is this at all possible, "natively"?
And, if not, is there a third-party tool or hack that you guys can recommend?

Comment: Do you want to mark the folder as read-only, or the files *within* the folder? Did you try to change the access permissions via "Get Info"?

Comment: Thanks! I'd prefer locking an entire folder. It seems to work on macOS locally, however, I can rename a file in a locked folder with the iPhone app "Files," which causes the file to be renamed in the cloud as well (which I verified using the file browser on icloud.com). Not so on the macOS copy of the file in the locked folder -- thus, it's a partial win.

Comment: I ws more thinking about actual file permissions (at the bottom of the Get Info window) but they may very well not get transferred via iCloud Drive

Comment: It sounds like you are using a Mac device. I am not 100% what your use case is, but if you fear that you accidentally change the files or delete them while you still need them I would recommend TM machine backups. Hard drives are cheap and it will give you much flexibility and safety since you can revert even your whole system if you need to.

Comment: From your trial and error it sounds like iOS doesn't respect the permissions. This would be a case where you would want to submit a bug report or feedback to Apple. I'm guessing there's funky ways you could use disk images or TrueCrypt containers but then it gets really tricky to view the contents on iOS. So, maybe until there's a fix stick with how it's working now and backup.